# Access Request Settings is raising the following error "Members cannot share this site because this site is missing a default members group."

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration, share

I have a team sub-site inside my sharepoint online team site, now the team sub-site has a unique permission with one security group, and the security group has Contribute permission . now when i access the "Site Settings" >> "Site Permission" >> "Access Request Settings", i got this error:-

[image]

so i am not sure what does this error mean? and how i can fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You probably deleted and recreated the Members group. Go to the following URL and select your current members group:

```
http://yourServer/sites/yourSite/_layouts/15/permsetup.aspx
```

Comment: Smith - MCT MVP thanks for the reply, But i am not sure what do you exactly mean by "Members group"?? now in my case i have a sub-site which have unique permission and for this sub-site i added a new security group to it, with contribute permission...and this security group have read-only permission on the parent root site.. so will my approach result in disabling the checkbox inside the "Access Request Settings"?? i can not understand the case?

Comment: did you have the chance to check my above comment?thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should set up default member group in the sub site.

You could follow the steps below:

1. Go to the affected subsite, click the gear and select Site settings.
2. Select Site permissions under Users and Permissions.
3. Check which default member group is missing in this page. ( Owners,  Members,  Visitors)
4. Modify the URL of this page to /_layouts/15/permsetup.aspx.
5. Create a new group for the missing default group. (You can also use an existing group.)
6. Save the changes.

There is a similar post:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_sharepoint/sharepoint-2013-users-cant-share-site/54017359-643b-49f8-8fd1-0df335dff3e4?auth=1

Comment: can you please clarify what do you mean by "default member group"? in my case i created a new sub-site and i define it to have unique permission, and inside the sub-site i added a new security group which have contribute permission on it , while this security group have Read-only on the root site.. so will this cause the error i am receiving ?? not sure.....

Comment: The default member groups, the names of them are “sub site Owners” , “sub site Members” and “sub site Visitors”.    The cause of the issue is that there is no default member groups.